# How does one share OneDrive (Office 365) documents without requiring authentication?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, google-docs

You might have seen online that when people share a Google Docs document, they can just post a link and anyone can open it, right?

Well, it turns out that when you do this with Office 365, making a **folder** public and posting a link, people get shown a log-in page where they have to enter their live ID.

So my question - am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to explicitly disable any sort of log in when publicly sharing Office 365 files or folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of January 2017 this is now possible.

It was announced at the [Microsoft Ignite conference in November 2016](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/OneDrive-for-Business/Announcement-Major-OneDrive-updates-at-Ignite-2016-include/td-p/15565) and [released in January 2016](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/11356467-create-anonymous-guest-links-on-the-folder-just-li#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)

Settings are controlled from the SharePoint admin centre in the Office 365 portal.

[image: SharePoint admin centre]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that have to be done before this will work.

- First your organization has to enable external sharing and enable
  anonymous sharing within sites.
  [image]
- Next they must ensure that the site where your document lives (MySite or SharePoint site), are enabled for "Share Links, and Invitations".  If it's only configured for "Share Links" then external users must sign in with a Microsoft ID to access the document.

You can see here - for me my sites (OneDrive for Business sites) don't allow for anonymous sharing.
[image]

but I have another site where we allow for posting documents that can be allowed anonymously (I also have a rule that deletes all documents here every 7 days).

[image]

Also - be sure when you select your Guest link it states "View or Edit - no sign in required"

**EDIT**

In regards to Sharing at the folder level - currently anonymous links are not available. If you share the Link, all users accessing it must logon with a Microsoft Account.

I do believe in the past there was mention of Microsoft rolling this feature out - but I don't see it on the RoadMap any longer.

Comment: Updated question - turns out my problem is with sharing **folders**, where the option of 'no login' isn't even present.

Comment: Added to my answer - Unfortunately O4B is not going to work the way you want it to.  That's something we've all been asking for - for quite a while (ala DropBox capability).